Free RAM memory from free command and Mobaxterm
I have several servers running Debian 10 or 11.
I use Mobaxterm (Link) for SSH into the servers to check the status of the services and the RAM usage.
I notice that the

free --mega -t

shows a amount of free RAM that differs from the one provided by the Mobaxterm (used RAM/total RAM in the red rectangle) in the bar on the bottom of the SSH windows.
This is the situation:

Why Mobaxterm shows 0.64 Gb of RAM are used and the "free" shows 170 Mb are used?
Which is the best way to check the used and the free RAM?
Why there is this difference between the two methods?
Thank you for the help!

Please [edit] your question and tell us what this "mobaxterm" thing is showing. Presumably it is explained in the documentation, right? Is it showing free? Used? Easily available? Including caches? Including swap? In what unit?

... is it showing memory on the server or the client? And so on. Here's what the free (1) shows: https://www.mankier.com/1/free#Description

what does head -v -n 8 /proc/meminfo show ?

@Archemar According to its manpage, free (1) uses the information from /proc/meminfo. So it is likely the numbers will be the same. The parameter --mega selects megabytes, while -m or --mebi selects mebibytes.

It should be noted that MobaXterm v24.0 Personal, build 5204 (free edition) doesn't display this status bar, unless it is the area near the bottom of the screen with the words "Unregistered version..." etc, so this can't be easily tested without buying the paid version.

Mobaxterm(*) use the following command line(**)
head -v -n 8 /proc/meminfo

I found that moba's status line was on line with both then command above, and free --mega -t.
e.g.
head -v -n 8 /proc/meminfo
==> /proc/meminfo <==
MemTotal:        3402300 kB
MemFree:          114212 kB

free --mega -t
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3483        2120         116          42        1246        1029

and moba : 2,14GB/3.24GB
(*) V21.0
(**) full command (line splited on ';')
bash -c while true
 do sleep 1
head -v -n 8 /proc/meminfo
 head -v -n 2 /proc/stat /proc/version /proc/uptime /proc/loadavg /proc/sys/fs/file-nr /proc/sys/kernel/hostname
 tail -v -n 16 /proc/net/dev
echo '==> /proc/df <=='
df
echo '==> /proc/netstat <=='
netstat -tupan
echo '==> /proc/who <=='
who
echo '==> /proc/end <=='
echo '##Moba##'
 done


This doesn't answer the question(s) at all.

Arcvhemar, it isn't clear to me if you are saying that the OP's numbers are consistent with each other (if so, please explain why) or if you could not reproduce the issue when you tried.

@Archemar thank you for the details about how Moba compute the RAM consumption.

From the current form of the answer it is unclear where is that script from and what is its connection to MobaXterm. If it is used by MobaXterm to display the numbers in the status line, some references (for proof), like permalinks to the source code, would be helpful. The question could use some grammar corrections as well, eg. "MobaXterm use the ...". In English, third person singular verbs end with -s. The meaning of "...on line with both then..." is also unclear.
